RASPBERRY PI ZERO - SSH working but PING fails in console mode
SFTP works well in Desktop mode autologin.
I mean I can send/get files from a host computer using filezilla (sftp - ssh file tansfer protocol)
but I cannot connect my raspberry pi0 with SFTP when it boots in console mode autologin.
I get "connection stopped after 20 seconds of inactivity etc..."
When I ping it (ping 192.168.1.13) from the host computer I get "impossible to reach the host destination".
sudo netstat -anp |less:

 Connexions Internet actives (serveurs et établies)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat        PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      534/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      513/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      513/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      534/sshd: /usr/sbin 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42470           0.0.0.0:*                           363/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           363/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 192.168.1.13:68         192.168.1.1:67          ESTABLISHED 483/NetworkManager  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           563/cups-browsed    
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                363/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 fe80::ac3:97b3:2637:546 :::*                                483/NetworkManager  
udp6       0      0 :::48229                :::*                                363/avahi-daemon: r 
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           483/NetworkManager  
Sockets du domaine UNIX actives(serveurs et établies)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Chemin
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8108     484/wpa_supplicant   /run/wpa_supplicant/p2p-dev-wlan0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6727     680/dbus-daemon      /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6413     595/systemd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6679     680/dbus-daemon      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5190     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6701     659/wireplumber      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5968     513/cupsd            /run/cups/cups.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5705     534/sshd: /usr/sbin  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6875     660/pipewire-pulse   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6511     657/pipewire         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5973     513/cupsd            /run/cups/cups.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5082     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6728     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5424     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6716     660/pipewire-pulse   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5978     563/cups-browsed     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5064     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6649     680/dbus-daemon      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6723     657/pipewire         
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6411     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/systemd/notify
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4997     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6414     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6412     595/systemd          
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6466     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5518     487/ModemManager     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4385     363/avahi-daemon: r  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6476     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5399     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5657     513/cupsd            
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4356     1/init               /run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6729     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6478     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/gcr/ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4364     1/init               /run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6480     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/keyring/control
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4414     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4371     1/init               /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      3653     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6482     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4376     1/init               /run/thd.socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3628     226/systemd-udevd    
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6484     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5658     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6486     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4805     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6488     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6490     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5386     483/NetworkManager   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6492     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/pipewire-0
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4399     364/cron             
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6494     595/systemd          /run/user/1000/pk-debconf-socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5482     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4183     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4392     364/cron             
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5423     484/wpa_supplicant   
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3559     1/init               
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4802     365/dbus-daemon      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3460     203/systemd-journal  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4311     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4310     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    5523     483/NetworkManager   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5419     487/ModemManager     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4431     363/avahi-daemon: r  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7467     662/rpi-connectd     /run/user/1000/rpi-connectd.socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      10303    1078/sudo            
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5997     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      10302    1076/sudo            
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      5593     365/dbus-daemon      
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4312     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      7875     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5717     529/dbus             
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3192     1/init               
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6143     595/systemd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6418     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      8053     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      7047     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5536     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6794     1/init               
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5575     513/cupsd            
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6538     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4450     363/avahi-daemon: r  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6913     659/wireplumber      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6549     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6204     595/systemd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6878     660/pipewire-pulse   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6799     708/rtkit-daemon     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      8043     917/bluetoothd       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6899     657/pipewire         /run/user/1000/pipewire-0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6897     657/pipewire         /run/user/1000/pipewire-0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6570     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6879     657/pipewire         /run/user/1000/pipewire-0
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6793     1/init               
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6693     595/systemd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6678     680/dbus-daemon      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5972     563/cups-browsed     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      5274     379/polkitd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5189     1/init               
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6877     680/dbus-daemon      /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6709     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6690     659/wireplumber      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      5468     424/systemd-logind   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5967     563/cups-browsed     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6717     660/pipewire-pulse   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6518     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6416     595/systemd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5081     379/polkitd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5706     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4904     428/thd              
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6722     657/pipewire         
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      5494     487/ModemManager     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4410     365/dbus-daemon      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5387     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4375     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5422     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      3607     226/systemd-udevd    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3624     226/systemd-udevd    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4396     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5519     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      5418     484/wpa_supplicant   
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3629     226/systemd-udevd    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5481     424/systemd-logind   
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4309     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  4      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3190     1/init               /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6056     571/login            
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3193     1/init               /run/systemd/private
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4432     367/avahi-daemon: c  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3195     1/init               /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5398     484/wpa_supplicant   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3196     1/init               /run/systemd/io.system.ManagedOOM
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4803     365/dbus-daemon      
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3209     1/init               /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4827     424/systemd-logind   
unix  13     [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3213     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4305     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  7      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3215     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3217     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      4430     363/avahi-daemon: r  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3219     1/init               /run/udev/control
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4180     327/systemd-timesyn  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5578     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      10293    1076/sudo            
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      6157     598/(sd-pam)         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6652     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4388     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      7873     917/bluetoothd       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      8050     917/bluetoothd       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      7471     662/rpi-connectd     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3456     203/systemd-journal  /run/systemd/journal/io.systemd.journal
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6166     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      3191     1/init               
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      7044     659/wireplumber      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5718     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      7472     680/dbus-daemon      /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6798     680/dbus-daemon      /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6561     662/rpi-connectd     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5533     483/NetworkManager   
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTE      8041     917/bluetoothd       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6927     680/dbus-daemon      /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6529     659/wireplumber      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      4806     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5901     563/cups-browsed     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6539     660/pipewire-pulse   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6876     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5902     1/init               /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5996     563/cups-browsed     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6898     659/wireplumber      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8057     484/wpa_supplicant   /run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6893     659/wireplumber      
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      6797     657/pipewire         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      5982     365/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket


sudo systemctl status ssh :

ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-09-19 21:25:28 CEST; 12min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 515 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 534 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 375)
        CPU: 486ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─534 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
sept. 19 21:25:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
sept. 19 21:25:28 raspberrypi sshd[534]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
sept. 19 21:25:28 raspberrypi sshd[534]: Server listening on :: port 22.
sept. 19 21:25:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
"




ip -a :

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:18:7b:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 86335sec preferred_lft 86335sec
    inet6 2a01:cb11:33:1d00:d81c:677b:810e:b470/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86372sec preferred_lft 572sec
    inet6 fd33:be24:6b4e:7a0e:78f8:5c38:a570:3f7e/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1743sec preferred_lft 1743sec
    inet6 fe80::ac3:97b3:2637:63c6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

from the host computer, ssh 192.168.1.13 says :


connect to ...etc ...port 22 :connection timed out

in the Desktop autologin mode there is one more line in netstat :

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.13:22         192.168.1.20:58183      ESTABLISHED 1206/sshd: pierre [


Welcome -- but it is impossible to tell from this whether the problem is even the Pi; "impossible to reach the destination" is a bit of a weird message for a ping, you should either explain specifically what software you are using for that or else edit in the actual error message (they are not all equivalent and they do have specific meanings, perhaps you meant "destination host unreachable" or "network unreachable", which are two different problems).  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73782/25985 ...I suspect you have problem #2, which does not mean any firewall is involved.

You might also want to clarify that by "FTP" you mean sftp, since it is a bit confusing what ssh has to do with this otherwise.  Finally, explain briefly how the Pi is configured to obtains its address as "static IP" is sort of implied, this is significant (read between the lines WRT problem #2).

the problem is not the pi as it works fine in desktop mode as I wrote: I can send/get files from a host computer with filezilla (sftp-ssh file transfer protocol).

the ping error msg is 'délai d'attente de la demande dépassé. Impossible de joindre l'hôte de destination' which is 'destination host unreachable'. A firewall on a raspberry pi , which acts only in console mode and not in Desktop mode ? Is it serious ?

RSPI ip4.adress: 192.168.1.13/24  when I ping it : ping 192.168.1.13 I get 'envoi d'une requête 'ping' 192.168.1.13 avec 32 octets de données : délai d'attente de la demande dépassé. Réponse de 192.168.1.20:impossible de joindre l'hôte de destination. x3 statistiques ping pour 192.168.1.13: paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus=2, perdus=2(perte 50%)

I actually wrote "which does not mean any firewall is involved", if you are not aware of one then there probably isn't; all of those problems can occur other ways. 50% packet loss is pretty strange on a LAN...  Most likely this is an DHCP related problem, it is possible to be connected to a wireless router such that you can access the internet through it but you are not properly accessible from other locals.  One way that can happen is an improper static IP config, but since you have not provided any information about the networking configuration not much more can be said.

thks goldilocks for you reply. I've updated my question with infos about the network status. I retrieved the data files with sftp(filezilla) from the host and the raspi in Desktop Autologin mode with no pb

same ssh status as for the Desktop mode config except CPU which is 486 ms instead of 8.869 s

in Desktop mode I get an additional line in netstat : tcp 0 0 192.168.1.13:22 192.168.1.20:58183  ESTABLISHED  1206/sshd: pierre [

The netstat output is not really relevant (beyond demonstrating further that ssh is running).  If you would like this question reopened, please go into detail about how networking is configured on the Pi -- what you are using (NetworkManager, systemd-networkd, etc), how you configured it, in particular whether or not you are using a static IP, and, if so, everything you did to enable that.  "Network status" is not the same as how networking software has been configured.

...Right now it seems to me you are evading the static IP issue perhaps because you do not like that evaluation (all apologies if that is not true, but it is sadly a common pattern), so you need to be explicit one way or another, and of course include the other network config details (WRT obtaining an IP address/DHCP lease).

no I don't use static IP

I don't understand what you wrote "you do not like that evaluation". All I want is to solve this issue

I've configured nothing on the pi, just default values of raspi-config

Okay, fair enough.  Do you know what version of the OS you are using?  cat /etc/os-release should tell you this.

os version 12 bookworm

I believe sshd is not launched because of the lines missing in netstat and ssh status

The ssh status shows it as running, pid 534. This is corroborated by netstat, tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 534/sshd.

Here's something to try. You will need a screen and keyboard connected to the Pi. While it is online:
sudo apt install isc-dhcp-client

This provides dhclient which makes it simpler to manually test the networking.  First you need to shut the current network system down.
If you are using the latest version of RPi OS I believe it uses NetworkManager (aka. "NM") by default.  You need to shut that down:
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant

The second one may not do anything (I am not sure if NM runs that as a separate service).
Now check sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.  It should be correct (ssid name and password) since it was working already.  Then:
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

This will occupy the current terminal and may take 30 seconds before it reports you are "associated" with the SSID.
From another terminal, run sudo dhclient -v wlan0.  This should report a lease has been obtained, then disappear into the background. ip addr show wlan0 should then show the IP address.
You should be able to access the internet and ping other things on the LAN.  The Pi should also be accessible from them.  If this is not the case, the problem is possibly with your router or other computer.
If that works...
Diagnosing why NetworkManager appears to be the problem may not be worthwhile. As with many things, GNU/Linux based operating systems have a wide variety of options even with regard to fundamental things such as network connectivity and management.
If all you need to manage is a singular DHCP LAN connection, wpa_supplicant + dhclient can suffice.  On 24/7 local devices like Pis I use dhcpcd primarily because it offers some fine tuning that allows me to keep things up online for long periods, but it is significantly more complicated, whereas dhclient doesn't even require any configuration (there is an /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf which applies and you can read about that in man dhclient.conf but it should be fine out-of-the-box).  It is still very reliable, I think; it's actually a sort of DHCP client reference implementation by the ISC who have been involved in the evolution of the protocol since its inception, amongst other things.
I do use it for on desktops/laptops because it seem to deal with the intermittent disconnections due to sleep etc. better than dhcpcd (or at least, the way I use the latter).  Here's my basic connect script:
#!/bin/bash

log=/var/log/simple-inet.txt
tty
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    if [ -e $log ]; then mv $log ${log}.$(date +"%s"); fi
    exec &> $log
fi

wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/terrapin.conf -i wlan0 -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -P /tmp/wpa_sup.pid -t -B
dhclient -v wlan0

Quick explanation of a few things:

The bit about the log applies mostly to dhclient's own output at startup although it will also catch shell errors (which shouldn't happen here but...).  The "then mv ..." bit rollover the previous log by appending a unix epoch timestamp (long number which is ascending, ie., highest = most recent).
wpa_supplicant has it's own log indicated in the command above.  The -P /tmp/wpa_sup.pid bit also writes the PID to a file which may be useful if something gets mixed up (it's possible to be running more than one wpa_supplicant, which normally is not a good thing, but there can only be one PID in that file.

You can put that in /etc/simple-inet.sh.  It should be owned root and set executable for root only (chmod 744 /etc/simple-inet.sh).
To then run this as a service (eg. at boot), first you need to disable NM:
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl mask NetworkManager

Check if wpa_supplicant is being used via a separate service with systemctl status wpa_supplicant.  If it is "enabled", do the same two steps with it.
Next you need a systemd service file for the new service:
[Unit]
Description="Simplified Networking"
Requires=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
StandardInput=null
ExecStart=/etc/simple-inet.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

Put that in /etc/systemd/system/simple-inet.service and enable it sudo systemctl enable simple-inet.  It should now run at boot and you can start and stop it manually:
systemctl start simple-inet
systemctl stop simple-inet

And check the current status:
systemctl status simple-inet


Great thks. I'll test it tonight and come back.

sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf returns : ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev update_config=1

sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf returns : Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant   then nothing (ie the prompt is blinking endlessly)

then I add in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf : network={ssid="Livebox-6C10" psk="--My-WEP-KEY"

then sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
returns : Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant wlan0 : Trying to associate with SSID 'Livebox' wlan0: Associated with d4:f8:29:9e:6c:10 wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to d4:f8:29:9e:6c:10 completed [id=0 id-str=] wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0 wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM6CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR

you write "from another terminal" what do you mean? I am in console mode.

Then I ran startX and I checked from the host machine that SFTP still doesn't work. I ran again sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf successfully and opened a 2nd terminal window to run sudo dhclient -v wlan0. I got : Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.3-P1 Copyright 2004-2022 Internet Systems Consortium. All rights reserved. For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp listening on LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:18:7b:10 Sending on LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:18:7b:10 Sending on Socket/fallback DHCDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval7

DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.13 from 192.168.1.1 DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.13 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 DHCPACK of 192.168.1.13 from 192.168.1.1 bound to 192.1681.13 -- renewal in 39703 seconds

ip addr returns : 2: wlan0:<BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER-UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether b8:27:eb:18:7b:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlan0 valid_lft 85926sec preferred_lft 85926sec inet6 fd33:be24:6b4e:7a0e:ba27:ebff:fe18:7b10/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr inet6 2a01:cb11:33:1d00:ba27:ebff:fe18:7b10/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr valid_lft 86395ec preferred_lft 595sec inet6 ....

when I ping 192.168.1.13 from my host windows machine it's alright : all packets received , 0 lost. loop delay in milliseconds minimum : 11 ms, maximum : 81 ms , mean value = 28 ms

and I can reach my raspi with SFTP !!! Thanks a lot goldilocks !

the I reboot and it still works.

I am not sure to understand why. Can you explain me a bit ? it's just a matter of network managing service ? DesktopManager failed and dhclient not ? Anyway it works.

Things like NetworkManager are designed to do everything for everybody but remain easy to use for basic users.  If that doesn't work out, it can turn into a bloated PITA.   I've added some stuff to the end above about how you can used dhclient on a permanent basis above.

WRT "you write "from another terminal" what do you mean? I am in console mode" -> Although you can only see one at a time, there are actually six text consoles by default, you can cycle through them with ctrl-alt-F[1-6].  If a GUI is running, one of them will be taken up by that.
